# C++ External Binary is locking the main program

Tags: c++, windows

I'm running a C++ program; however, it, unfortunately, needs to call an external program in Windows to get some results. The problem is that the external program has a part that asks user "push enter to exit". This makes impossible for me to run my program autonomously, because It is locking the whole program until enter pressed. Each turn, I need to push enter to exit that program. Is there any way to make this possible?

Note: External program is an exe, so I cannot touch it.

Comment: Call it non-blocking (i.e., from a different thread).

Comment: It depends on how you are calling the external program. Which API ?

Comment: I am using system("aaaa.exe"). I think running from different thread does not solve the problem, since main thread needs that output to run properly.

Comment: If you want the output from a program you could use [`_popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) instead.

Comment: A second thread will solve your problem. Just retrive the value and give it to your main thread. Alternatively you can search for the button's handle and then send a click-signal via Windows' message system to the other application.

Comment: More regarding your problem, the program you "call" is probably doing `system("pause")` at the end, a generally bad habit that many beginners seem to do for no special reason. The *proper* solution (in my not so humble opinion) is to modify the program you call so it doesn't do something like wait for a keypress at the end.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231188/how-do-i-run-a-program-from-another-program-and-pass-data-to-it-via-stdin-in-c-o

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I actually don't know why that program is written in that way. Maybe they want to make it more "user friendly". I'm looking popen now.

Comment: @cagatayodabasi You could also look into the Windows API functions [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CreatePipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then you can also read the output from the program, but more importantly it will allow you to write to the programs standard input so you could write the newline it needs to end. Also see e.g. [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Actually, I would rather recommend you to use `CreateProcess` and pipes, as `_popen` only allows either reading, or writing, to the child process, not both simultaneously. You *could* use `_popen` in write-mode, and redirect standard output to a file using `>` (like in a command window), then write the newline.

Comment: Actually, I want to use OS specific API's as low as possible to change platform easily. If it's possible, I prefer to use standard libraries.

Comment: As a result, I changed my system function with _popen thanks to @JoachimPileborg, @WorldSEnder; still there are some problems if I use _pclose to terminate the program it again wants to push enter key; however, (I know this is really really bad way) I'm not using _pclose, each turn I'm just using _popen to call the external. Until I found a safe way, I will be doing in this way. If you guys, write your comments as answer I can select them as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send that "enter" to the external program. @Joachim commented that `_popen` works to capture output, but it also allows you to send input to your external program - such as `\n`. (It may need `\r\n`, experiment).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way...but...

You can try to run the exe file with `CreateProcess()`
and then use the `FindWindow()` API to get the exe window and use `SendMessage()` to send it the enter key...

Another **NOT** so recommended option is to call `TerminateProcess()` with the handle from the `CreateProcess() PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure after some waiting time...

Hope it helps...